# Swift Package Firebase version not resolving while using xcworkspace file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I just added the first Cocoapod to my iOS project.  When I open up the .xcworkspace file to start utilizing the new features, the original Firebase Swift package starts to fail.  When I build I get the error of

```
Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of 'googleappmeasurement' match the requirement 8.14.0 and root depends on 'googleappmeasurement' 8.14.0.
```

[image: Error Occurrence]

I have tried setting my Swift Package to major version 8.0.0 and minor version 8.13.0 and I continue to get this error.  Per Github Firebase page, the 8.14.0 version is not yet released.  However I seem to still be referencing it?

https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement/issues/22

My current package dependency:
[image: Current Swift Package Dependency Setting]

When I return to the .xcodeproj file I have no issues with Firebase Swift Package, but of course cannot run the new cocoa pod.

Interestingly, I noticed that the Swift Package at the bottom of the xcworkspace file is greyed out, while it is populated in the xcodeproj file.

XCWorkspace File:
[image: xcworkspace package greyed out and no sub folders]

XCodeProj File:
[image: Xcode project file shows package is correctly installed]

I feel like there's some setting to enable both pods and packages simultaneously that I'm missing, but just can't find.  I've tried resolving package dependencies from the File menu and the terminal line as well as multiple restarts.  All help appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: What problem do you want to resolve? googleappmeasurement package resolution? You included a link to the discussion on GitHub that explains what to do–use a fixed existing version for the package. The latest one is 8.12.0 ATM (https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement/tags).

Comment: I tried that solution, and the Xcode build is still looking for an 8.14 version.  As you can see in the loaded files from the xcodeproj file, I have the 8.12 version in my package manager.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the packages to build correctly while in the xcworkspace file.  If I can't do that I can't seem to simultaneously use cocoa pods and swift package manager?  Seems really limiting.

Comment: You definitely should be able to use both at the same time. I had been using this combination for ages in my projects.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've tried to fix the googleappmeasurement version in Package dependencies as Exact 8.12.0 instead of using Up to Next Major, right?